$I$ is parallel with respect to the Levi-Civita connection if and only if $\omega $ is parallel. $I:$almost non-complex structure
Let $(M, g)$ be a Riemannian manifold, let $ I $ be an almost complex structure compatible with $g$ and $\omega $ the corresponding 2-form (that is, $ω^\flat = g^\flat \circ I$). Let $\nabla$ be the Levi-Civita connection on $ TM $. I want to show that $I$ is parallel with respect to the Levi-Civita connection if and only if $\omega $  is parallel, that is
$$\nabla(IX) = I\nabla X ,\quad\forall X \in {\scr X} (M) \iff ∇\omega = 0$$.
This is what I have done:
($\Rightarrow$)
I am not sure how to interpret the condition $\nabla(IX) = I\nabla X \quad\forall X \in {\scr X} (M) \tag 1$. Normaly I see the connection in books with an additional vector field as subindex like this $\nabla_YX$. I will suppose the given condition means that
$ \text{for any } X,Y\in {\scr X}(M), \nabla_Y(IX) = I\nabla_Y X \tag 2$
I hope you can confirm or correct this
Then to prove $\nabla\omega=0$,take $ X,Y,Z \in{\scr X}(M)$ and first use formula (4.12) that I found in Lee's Introduction to Riemannian geometry (see below)
$\nabla\omega(Y,Z,X)=\nabla_X\omega(Y,Z)=X(\omega(Y,Z))-\omega(\nabla_X Y,Z)-\omega(Y,\nabla_X Z)$
Now I use the compatibility condition between $ I,\omega $and $g$ which means that $\omega(A,B)=g(IA,B)=<IA,B>$ and the assumption $\nabla_Y(IX) = I\nabla_Y X$(actually with X and Y interchanged)
$=X(<IY,Z>)-<I\nabla_X Y,Z>-<IY,\nabla_X Z>$
$=X(<IY,Z>)-<\nabla_X (IY),Z>-<IY,\nabla_X Z>$
The last two terms I use the compatibility of $\nabla$ and $g$
$ <\nabla_X (IY),Z>+<IY,\nabla_X Z>=\nabla_X<IY,Z> \tag 3$
From this I get:
$\nabla\omega(Y,Z,X)=X(<IY,Z>)-\nabla_X<IY,Z>\tag 4$
Questions:
1) This is where I am stuck,  how do I show this is 0? My guess is that it is 0 because since $<IY,Z>$ is a scalar product of vector fields,the result is a scalar function, then the covariant derivative is just ordinary differentiation:$\nabla_X<IY,Z>=X<IY,Z>$.Is this correct?
2) To prove ($\Leftarrow$) I have that  $\nabla \omega =0$
which means that for all $ X,Y,Z \in{\scr X}(M), \nabla (Y,Z,X)=\nabla_X(Y,Z)=0$ but I don't know what to do from here, I tried giving particular values like $Z=IY$ to see if it reduces to some expression where I can use the non-degeneracy of $g$ or $\omega$, but no luck yet. How do I prove this part?


